# Plotting two splots in one gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I currently draw a helix with some points in a gnuplot script. Now I want to draw a second helix inside the other helix, with formula: splot [t=-1.5*pi:6*pi] sin(t),cos(t),t*0.23246067325

However, it doesn't seem to work if I just add the command to the script. Is there a specific way to do it?

```
reset
clear
set parametric
unset key
unset tics
unset border 

set termoption dashed
set termoption dashlength 2

set object rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind fillcolor rgb 'white' fillstyle solid noborder

set style line 4 lc rgb 'black' pt 7
set style line 7 lc rgb 'royalblue' pt 7 ps 10

splot [t=-1.5*pi:6*pi] sin(t),cos(t),t*0.23246067325 ls 4, '-' w p ls 7,  '-' w p ls 7
0.0 1.0 2.9211869733608857 #G#
e
-1.0 0.0 4.016632088371217 #E#
e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `t` is used for 2D plots. For 3d plots (`splot`) use `u` and `v` instead.

It seems that you only need `u`, so I have removed your "`[t=-1.5*pi:6*pi]`" and replaced it by `set urange [-1.5*pi:6*pi]` before entering the `splot` command:

(You have specified only one helix, so I have scaled the first one a little bit to generate a second one. And the `set termoption dashlength 2` did not work for me, so I removed it.)

```
reset
clear
set parametric
unset key
unset tics
unset border

set object rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind fillcolor rgb 'white' fillstyle solid noborder

set style line 4 lc rgb 'black' pt 7
set style line 7 lc rgb 'royalblue' pt 7 ps 10

set urange [-1.5*pi:6*pi]

splot sin(u), cos(u), u*0.23246067325 ls 4 ,\
      0.8*sin(u), 0.8*cos(u), u*0.23246067325 ls 1 ,\
      '-' w p ls 7,  \
      '-' w p ls 7
0.0 1.0 2.9211869733608857 #G#
e
-1.0 0.0 4.016632088371217 #E#
e
```

This generates the following output:

[image]